# In-line column assignments in Python/Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a bunch of points and need to select a subset of them, add a value to the x coordinates and store the information in the original points.
I need to do it without loops or intermediate assignments.

```
import numpy as np
points=np.array([[100.  , 100.  , 100.  ],
   [  0.  ,  -2.75,   0.  ],
   [  0.  ,  -2.75,   5.  ],
   [  0.  ,  -1.9 ,   3.15],
   [  0.  ,  -1.9 ,   3.35]])
```

then trying:

```
points[[3,4,0]][:,[0]]+=2
```

or

```
points[[3,4,0]][:,[0]]=points[[3,4,0]][:,[0]]+2
```

the original points variable does not change. 
Any ideas? I suspect I am missing some stupid stuff...

Comment: That's an invalid slice. Did you mean to write points[[3,4,0]][:,[0]]?

Comment: Yes you can use that. It was just an example of a much more complex pattern for the selected rows. (Actually they are stored in another list...).

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to edit first column of those rows use:

```
points[[3,4,0], 0] += 2
points
#[[ 102.    100.    100.  ]
# [   0.     -2.75    0.  ]
# [   0.     -2.75    5.  ]
# [   2.     -1.9     3.15]
# [   2.     -1.9     3.35]]
```

Comment: Got it. Stupid mistake. Tnx.